# No display output event mid-update of Ubuntu 23.04 + NVidia 1070ti + nvidia-driver-5.35

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, display, 23.04

When upgrading my Ubuntu 23.04 + NVidia 1070ti + nvidia-driver-5.35, I'm encountering a situation where the monitor stops getting a signal, goes into standby, and I'm unable to restore the signal.  This occurs with 100% of the updates that include an nvidia or kernal update and seems to have started months ago.  Although I'm not confident on the timeline.

To recover, I wait 5 minutes to ensure the upgrade is complete, ssh to the computer, and run a `sudo shutdown -h now` command (or -r).  Interestingly, the machine never completes the shutdown/restart so I wait a few more minutes and then hard reset with the power button.  I've encountered no issues on startup.

Here's what I've been able to ascertain.

- It occurs during upgrades (observation).
- It seems to happen at the `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:` stage of the upgrade
- The `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log` show no indications of errors or truncation mid-upgrade.
- The usual key combinations to bring up other terminals do not work for restoring video output.
- ssh'ing in and shutting down remotely encounters another "hang" of some type and the machine will not reboot/shutdown despite waiting hours.
- No issues on startup after shutdown/reboot.

I could really use some ideas for things to investigate here please.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: New additional information.  The behaviour happened as I was working on my computer today.  A quick ssh from my phone showed that there was an unattended upgrade going on.  I'm hoping this info should help narrow down the problematic process/package that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue went away on its own. I'm going to close this question and just assume it was a bad update on an NVidia/graphical package that eventually got fixed.

Comment: Once an Nvidia package was "phased", and didn't download, so the driver rebuild failed.  Booted the former kernel/driver, and forced the download, then things worked.